# Textures in different positions from bodies in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I'm making a prototype project in LibGDX and I'm using Box2D for the physics.
I've created a map and added some collision to him, i added entities that has circle shapes too. 
These circles are correctly positioned in the World of Box2D, but the textures that i want to get fixed to them are getting based on other coordinates, from the user camera I think.
This is the result:
[image]

My render method in the base "Entity" class

```
public void update() {
    handleInput();
}

public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    update();
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(texture, body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y);
    batch.end();
}
```

My render method in the BaseMap class

```
private void update(OrthographicCamera camera) {
    camera.position.x = player.getPosition().x;
    camera.position.y = player.getPosition().y;
    world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);
}

public void render(OrthographicCamera camera, SpriteBatch batch) {
    update(camera);
    renderer.setView(camera);

    batch.begin();
    renderer.render();
    batch.end();

    for(Entity entity : entities) {
        entity.render(batch);
    }
}
```

The renderer here is a OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. Was there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: I need to attach the Box2D bodies of the entities with their Textures. The bodies are being rendered with reference to the map itself and the textures with reference to the camera. As you can see, some textures are off the map limits, even if they are making the same moves of theirs bodies

Comment: Bodies are the empty circles, the debug mode of Box2D

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're setting the matrix for the batch as well:

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

Likewise for the Box2DDebugRenderer:

```
renderer.render(world, camera.combined);
```

This is assuming you aren't using a scaled box2d world.